# Define title attribute as language string

Tags: html, image, attr

Is it possible to define the content of the title attribute on a image as language string which can be overrided in multi language site?

I think about this style:

```
<img title="tooltip_mod".....>
```

Defining a tooltip_mod ini file that sets the text for more languages.

For example:

Tooltip text (in fact the Title attribute) in English is "Click for fullscreen" and in French "Cliquez pour plein écran".

So at the English site the tooltip on hovering over the image is "Click for...." and on the french site will be diplayed "Cliquez pour ...."

In my tooltip_mod.ini  in the EN folder i would define:
tooltip_mod="Click for..."
and in the FR folder i would define in this ini file tooltip_mod="Cliquez pour ..."

Any suggestions if this is possible with a language string of some kind?

Comment: Whatever system you are using for handling your translation strings already (but which you've told us nothing about) should work fine with title attributes just as it should for any other part of the content.

Comment: Sorry. I'm on joomla 4 which handles normally the multi language part. The problem is that i don't know how to define the text-part of the tilte attribute in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const tt = {
  "en-gb": {
    tooltip_mod: "Click for..."
  },
  "fr-fr": {
    tooltip_mod: "Cliquez pour ..."
  },
  "nl-nl": {
    tooltip_mod: "Klik hier voor ..."
  }
}
const defaultLang = "en-gb", lg = document.querySelector("html").getAttribute("lang")?.toLowerCase(); // the ?. optional chaining will handle where there is no lang attr
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const tooltip = tt[lg] || tt[defaultLang]; // the || will handle if lang not found
  document.querySelectorAll("[title]").forEach(ele => ele.title = tooltip[ele.title] || ele.title)
})
```

```html
<html lang="fr-FR">
<img title="tooltip_mod" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/994/598/png-clipart-translation-dictionary-angol-magyar-english-language-hungarian-french-dictionary-orange-logo-thumbnail.png" />

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe silly questions but:  1. the code should be in which sort of file? Can it be in custom.js?  2. whats does "ele" mean?  3. this kind of coding is that loaded each time a page loads thus dynamically or replacing in the html of the site the title attribute?

Comment: but what?......

Comment: i've already edited my comment.  I still have some issues with clicking to quick on enter:(

Comment: on my site in the head is this code for language selection <html lang="fr-fr" dir="ltr">, i presume that this should replace the tag  fr or en in your example?

Comment: Tried the code in custom.js. Changed image title to "tooltip_mod". Put my lang code "fr-fr" in the code. Result: tooltip on hover is now only showing the text "tooltip_mod". So in fact the text within the " " of the title attribute is not seen as "variable".  Also the tooltip layout which is caused by data-bs-toggle="tooltip" attribute is now ignored and the layout is fallen back to standard.

Comment: A thougt: is my "tooltip" constant interferring with bootstrap's own "tooltip"? If so what to change to use my "own" constant with that is not conflicting for example "clicktip"? Just this lines change to :   const clicktip = tt[lg];
  document.querySelectorAll("[title]").forEach(ele => ele.title = clicktip[ele.title] || ele.title)????

Comment: After editing the code in the sence of the previous comment, this function is no longer working: 'jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#main img").click(function(){
    this.requestFullscreen()})});'  The tooltip is showing the exact text of the title but clicking on the image does not give fullscreen.

Comment: I have NO idea. You have not posted ANY of your code and you did not even tag jQuery.

Comment: There is nothing so far in my code that should give any issue with bootstrap unless bootstrap is looking for title="tooltip_mod"

Comment: I updated the code to handle "fr-fr"  - if that gives errors, then it blocks all script. so look in the console for errors

Comment: Wow with the adaptions you made all is working perfectly also with the text tooltip_mod. I've added the same subroutine for Dutch (nl-nl) and that also working perfectly. THANKS

Comment: I added a fallback for en-gb if no lang attribute or empty lang